# Change to the way I measured the size of a media response

Tags: image, api, karate

Hi Peter or fellow karate user,

Having just upgraded from 1.2 to 1.4 I found that responseBytes has changed and didn't see anything in the documentation about an expected change.

I used the following format to test my site is returning media:

```
Scenario: 00 - TESTER for STACKOVERFLOW getMedia where media type is: Video
    # Test steps
    Given url 'https://www.afl.com.au/resources/v4.8.10/i/elements/afl-watermark-left.png'
    When method get
    Then status 200
    # Match contentType and contentLength response headers
    And match responseHeaders['Content-Type'][0] == 'image/png'
    # Observed 22000 as of 05-05-23
    And assert responseHeaders['Content-Length'][0] >= '10000'
    # Asserting against the content length
    And def responseSize = karate.sizeOf(responseBytes)
    # Observed 22000 as of 05-05-23
    And assert responseSize >= '10000'
```

The responseBytes built-in variable used to return a list array, visible when I printed it, but now returns something else. Now the 'responseSize' variable contains -1, which would happen if reponseBytes is not a list anymore.
Thank you,

I was expecting the `karate.sizeOf(responseBytes)` to resolve to an int, which shows the size of the image in bytes and then I would be able to make an assertion against this which would alert me if the bytes fell below my threshold.

I have tried other functions, like 'response' and was looking for a Js way to measure the size of the response.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with `responseBytes.length` that should work and is the recommended usage.

You are right that karate.sizeOf() does not handle bytes, we [opened an issue](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2310).